# Как вывести все данные из CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

Нужно с Node сервера отправить все документы которые находятся в базе CouchDB. Использовал метод list, но он не показывает всех свойств, что есть в документе. А метод get работает только с одним документом. Вот примеры кода:

```
var base = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984/table');

    app.post('/data', function (req, res) {
    base.list(function (err, body) {
        res.send(body);
    });

});
```

Например создаем документ

```
db.insert({ crazy: true }, 'rabbit', function(err, body) {
    if (!err){
        console.log(body);
    }
    console.log(body);
});
```

Когда клиент принимает, то в объекте:

> "rabbit"
>   key
>   :
>   "rabbit"
>   value
>   :
>   Object
>   rev
>   :
>   "6-3f47c979be6a39124ae0ce5760ddf9ac"

Отсутствует параметр crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить о самом CouchDB, то в нем есть метод [`GET {db}/_all_docs`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#get--db-_all_docs), который возвращает все документы из базы. По-умолчанию, тело ответа содержит только *ключи и ревизии* документов. Для включения в ответ самих документов, существует специальный GET параметр `include_docs`:

```
GET /db/_all_docs?include_docs=true HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:5984
```

В [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano), как для этого используется метод [db.list](https://github.com/dscape/nano#dblistparams-callback). Однако, вопрос получения самих документов (а не только ключей и ревизий) так же определяется флагом `include_docs`:

```
var db = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984/db');

db.list({include_docs: true}, function(err, data) {
    // ...
});
```

А еще, в репозитории nano, есть [примеры](https://github.com/dscape/nano/tree/master/examples) использования библиотеки. Пример использования `db.list` для получения пачки документов там [тоже есть](https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/master/examples/bulk_transform.js#L29).